# Node.js catch statement return does not stop executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord bot with the help of node.js
In which I need to call a function that may return discord API errors I handle them like this

```
interaction.user.send("Hi")
.catch(() => {return interaction.reply("...");
console.log("shouldnt run if an error accured")
```

However whenever that API error accurse the return statement unlike normally does not stop the code execution.
How do I stop the console.log statement in this code from executing when the exception accurse ?

Answer (score 1):

the js is asynchronous so it puts the request of API in execution queue(not wait for response from api) and continue its execution that's why your console statement is running even if the error occurs.

```
interaction.user.send("Hi")
.then(() => {
// do whatever you want when it succeed
})
.catch((error) => { 
// handle error
 });
```

you can also checkout async await for the same.

Comment: Please don't write code only answers, you should explain what the OP did wrong, what you changed and how it works

Comment: I tried it out and sadly it for some reason didnt work also you need a closing ) at the end

Comment: I have updated the answer so you can handle what to do when sending message is succeed and when failed.

Comment: I have added more description in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @ParthPatel indicates, `interation.user.send()` is returning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which may not be rejected immediately upon error.  Statements such as your `console.log()` will run before an error has a chance to occur and be caught.

However, these days there is the async await syntax you can use, which may help you simplify your code a bit depending on what you're trying to do.

```
try {
  await interaction.user.send("Hi");
  console.log('Shouldn\'t run if error occurred.');
} catch(e) {
  interaction.reply('...');
}
```

Note that you can only use `await` inside of an `async` function, declared like this:

```
async function doSomething() {
  // Do something here...
}
```

You can find more information here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await